# Function call after buffer overflow

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I've seen a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXQefYKWjz4

I don't understand 2 things:

- I can't see the function call, but it happens.
- How he got a specific number, which he wrote to the file.

He is trying to write specific value(perhaps address of function to some position in the stack). Why it is possible? How I can repeat this?

Comment: Technically, the function is not called, the instruction pointer *returns* to the code of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, What happens here is that he stores the hardcoded address of the function foo() in the 'file' that he reads into the variable 'x'. He stored it as '**134513853**' which when converted to hexadecimal becomes: **0x80484bd** which must be the **address** of the **function foo()**.
So, in order of execution,
the program reads the **address of foo()** from the file and copies it into **x**. Then it **overwrites** the buffer with this address such that after it **overflows** the buffer, it overwrites the **return address**.

For example:

If this is what the function stack looks like,

> Buffer----------------->
>
> EBP ----------------->
>
> Return address --------> some 0x value    <--- EIP

Post overflow it will look like this:

> Buffer-----------------> 0x80484bd
>
> EBP--------------------> 0x80484bd
>
> **Return Address**---------> 0x80484bd        <----**EIP**

Lets not bother with little-endian for now. So, when the function main() ends, the execution will resume from the address stored at the 'Return address' thereby diverting the execution to function foo() and printing the string, "Welcome to my...".

As for your second question, i think the guy who made the video has disabled ASLR and Stack Cookies.

**ASLR or Address Space Layout Randomization** randomizes key parts of the executable such that a function exists at different addresses on every new instance.

**Stack Cookie/Canary** is a random runtime generate value which is placed in between the local variables and the return address such that any overflow will have to first overwrite the cookie value. This cookie value is checked before the function ends and if there is a mismatch, the function exits thereby not letting the execution flow being diverted to the attacker controlled return address.

In order to repeat this, u will have to disable ASLR on your system, on Ubuntu this can be achieved by typing the following in your terminal such as Bash:

**echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space**

Then, you will have to compile your program without the stack cookie in the following way:

**gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o test test.c**

For more information:
ASLR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#Canaries

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A buffer overflow is a kind of 'problem' that lets the program potentially write over its own memory stack.

This does two things:

- overwrites IP's (instruction pointer's) return address with a trivial value
- (over)writes data in the stack, meant to be used as function parameters.

When the current function exits, the instruction pointers changes to the address in the stack. If that adress is that of malicious code, the code will be executed as if it were the program's.

This could allow one to potentially execute code with, for example *root* priviledges, if done inside a program that uses such priviledges.